# Detecting support for beginElement()

Tags: animation, svg, internet-explorer-9, modernizr, feature-detection

I'm using `beginElement()` to start an SVG animation in my web app:

```
document.getElementById("item").beginElement();
```

But this causes the following error in IE9 and up (which [doesn't support it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464647(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'beginElement'
```

I don't mind the animation not working in IE9, but I need to prevent the error from occurring. How do I set up a check so that `beginElement()` only gets called if the browser supports it? E.g.:

```
if (hasSupport) {
    document.getElementById("item").beginElement();
}
```

I tried a detection technique [like this](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#canvas):

```
return !!document.getElementById("item").beginElement();
```

But that always returns `false`, even in browsers that I know support it (like Firefox).

I also looked at using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), but it doesn't have a test for `beginElement()`.

Comment: Modernizr has a test for [SMIL](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-misc), that you could use, though it's a little more general. But there's no real point in checking for `beginElement` if SMIL isn't supported as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sniff the method to see if it exists before executing it.

```
var item = document.getElementById("item");

if ('beginElement' in item) {
    item.beginElement();
}
```

Modernizr uses `in` form, however `if (item.beginElement)` would work just the same.